# Android crash on getActiveNetworkInfo()

Tags: java, android, permissions

The error message says

> Neither user 10093 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE

And I have added "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" to the manifest:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> ```

Why does this happen and How can I fix it? I'm emulating on Nexus One - 2.3.7. - API10

Code cut:

```
ConnectivityManager cm =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
    System.out.print("Debb: there is internet\n");
}
```

Whole Error Log:

> 04-27 22:26:13.781    1522-1522/com.example.nekitamo E/AndroidRuntime﹕
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nekitamo/com.example.nekitamo.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10024
>   nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: ConnectivityService: Neither user 10024 nor current process has
>   android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1322)
>               at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
>               at android.net.IConnectivityManager$Stub$Proxy.getActiveNetworkInfo(IConnectivityManager.java:345)
>               at android.net.ConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.java:251)
>               at com.example.nekitamo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you show your total error logs from your logcat..

Comment: i've just added it to problem description

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was because i was running it on UI thread. From api level 10 that is unsupported.

Answer (score 3):

```
Neither user 10024 nor current process has android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
```

Seems your Manifest file lacks

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: It does not lack it! I posted it in problem description.

Answer (score 0):

This should a bug of Android ICS framework.
Try to add this permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

After, compile, performs a cleaning and finally rebuild the project.

Comment: I already did that. I pasted everything I added in permissions in problem description. It's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

step 1:
put

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

into manifest file 
and,

step 2:

put mouse cursor between cm and get.`(cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();)`
Then type getActionNetworkInfo(); again.then automatically popup it.Then click Tab button.Then run your project.
I faced same problem and worked it to me.